# How to configure prefix for own migration filename

Tags: maven, flyway

I want add Flyway (flyway-maven-plugin v.3.2.1) in to existing app. This app used migration files (writted in pure SQL) where file name have this pattern: `1023_pos_column_size_extension.sql`

How i can configure `sqlMigrationPrefix, sqlMigrationSeparator, sqlMigrationSuffix`?

Now i have:

```
<sqlMigrationPrefix></sqlMigrationPrefix>
<sqlMigrationSeparator>_</sqlMigrationSeparator>
<sqlMigrationSuffix>.sql</sqlMigrationSuffix>
```

but this configuration accepted only filename `V2__Add_people.sql`

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the Flyway website in the [Maven documentation](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/):

> Limitation: Due to a long standing Maven bug it is not possible to configure empty values this way. You must use one of the other configurations ways instead.